# PHP / Mysql - Load file and query records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tried a few things here but somehow I can't seem to get my records back via PHP to perform subsequent action.  Essentially I'm loading records into a staging table (WORKS), calling a proc to then migrate them to my live table (WORKS), and then I need to simply loop each record imported to produce an image. If I echo out the query and run it via Workbench, I'm getting my data back, but somehow in PHP the query isn't returning anything, what am I missing?

```
public function import_members() {
    $this->filepath=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->filepath)); 

    $status = "success";
    $msg = "";

    $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $this->filepath ."' INTO TABLE temp_imported 
          CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
          FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
          OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
          LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
          IGNORE 1 LINES 
          (fname,lname,email,phone,address,city,province,postal,dob,member_no)";

          echo $query . "<br><br>";

          // EXECUTE LOAD - ON SUCCESS
          if ($this->conn->query($query)) {
              try {
                  // CALL PROC TO IMPORT DATA INTO LIB_MEMBERS
                  $stmt = $this->conn->query("CALL sp_import_members(@rowcount)");

                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
                      $records = $row[0];
                  }

                  mysqli_free_result($stmt);
                  $msg = "File was imported successfully! <br> A total of " . $records . " records were imported from your file" ; 
                } 
                catch (Exception $ex) {
                    $msg = $ex ;
                    $status = 'danger';
                }

               echo $status . "<br><br>";

               if ($status == "success"){ 
                    // GENERATE BARCODE IMAGES FOR IMPORTED
                    $querybar = "Select barcode from lib_members where barcode is not null and DATE(datein) = date(now())";
                    echo $querybar . "<br><br>";

                    $stmt2 = $this->conn->query($querybar);
                    $rownum = $stmt2->num_rows;

                    if ($rownum){
                        echo $rownum;
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "NO";
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $msg = "There was a problem importing your file";
            }

            echo "<div style='width:40%; margin:0 auto; text-align:center; font-size:12px;' class='alert alert-". $status ."' role='alert'>" . $msg . "</div>";
        }
 }
```

My output currently shows this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/DB/Sites/Scan_MASTER/imported/members.csv' INTO TABLE temp_imported CHARACTER SET 'latin1' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (fname,lname,email,phone,address,city,province,postal,dob,member_no)

success

Select barcode from lib_members where barcode is not null and DATE(datein) = date(now())

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/db/Sites/Scan_MASTER/_members.php on line 590

NO
```

Line 590 consist of my "num_rows" line

Comment: check for errors on the query then tell us what it is

Comment: I tried the mysqli_error($querybar) but not getting anything back, which is why I figured I'd just try the row_num option.   If I run the "Select barcode" statement in Workbench, I'm getting my records back just fine, so seems to be specific to php sequence somehow, at least I think.

Comment: `mysqli_error($querybar)` - `$querybar` and you're using `$this->conn` as the connection in the query. Those don't match. `mysqli_error()` needs to use the connection argument, not the query. That's why you're not getting the real error.

Comment: I'm getting back "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now", so quick google search reveals I need to "store results" first? This is the only instance where I have back to back queries using mysli so found it odd I wasn't getting this error elsewhere and had no issues... need to wrap my brain around how the "query" and "result" methods work... having trouble with this.  THANKS A MILLION!!

Comment: You're most welcome.

Comment: Here's a reference link that may be of help http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php

Comment: If you look at the following "resultmode" section in http://php.net/mysqli_query, it indicates I should "free results" from the previous query, which I'm doing from the previous query statement, so could you possibly clarify this for me?  Is my mysqli_free_result($stmt); out of sequence in order for subsequent query to run?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php states: *"You should always free your result with mysqli_free_result(), when your result object is not needed anymore."* - So, if you still need those results, you would need to not use it; seems to be thing to do here, yet I could be wrong.

Comment: Despite adding the free_result after my first query and even moving the subsequent call to another function, am still getting the same error, and if I close the connection, my second query won't run unless I re-open.   Not sure why I can't get this "free_result" method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `commit` after line `$this->conn->query($query)`

Comment: The records appear to be inserted on the proc call, so I assume auto-commit is on default no?

Comment: I do not know. Probably no. Just try.

Comment: I did, didn't change the outcome... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a way to get around the issue by using a prepare and execute statement for my proc call rather than using the "query" method in both instances.  Might not be pretty or the ideal fix, but it works.